# A two variable recurrence relation with conditionals

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, recurrences, difference-equations

I have arrived at the combinatorial problem of enumerating certain types of ballot paths. This has led to analyzing the sequence defined by the following recurrence

$$
f(n,m) = \begin{cases} f(n, \thinspace m-1) + f(n-m, \thinspace m-1), & \text{ if } n \leq \left \lceil \binom{m}{2}/2 \right \rceil \\  f(n-m, \thinspace m-1), & \text{ if } n > \lceil \binom{m}{2}/2 \rceil \end{cases}
$$

where $f(n,0) = \begin{cases} 1, & \text{ if } n = 0 \\ 0, & \text{ if } n \neq 0 \end{cases}$

I note that the recurrence $f(n, \thinspace m) = f(n, \thinspace m-1) + f(n-m, \thinspace m-1)$ alone counts the number of partitions of $n$ into distinct parts bounded by $m$, so a closed formula for my sequence is probably out of the question.

**Question**: Is it possible to obtain a generating function for this sequence?

I have seen many threads here regarding generating functions for recurrences with two parameters, but none of them deals with recurrences including a conditional.

In fact, any useful info regarding such recurrences would be appreciated.

Comment: I am having some difficulty seeing your recurrence producing more than $f(n,m) = 1$  when $n=\frac{m(m+1)}{2}$ and $0$ otherwise.  What do you think are the values of for example $f(0,1)$, $f(1,3)$, $f(4,3)$ or $f(5,4)$? Perhaps I have misunderstood, or you may have a typo

Comment: The examples you mention are all zero. What you are expressing with e.g $f(5,4)$ is how many ways you can partition the integer $5$ into distinct parts $\lambda = (\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_k)$ from the set $\{1,2,3,4 \}$ such that $\lambda_1 + \cdots + \lambda_i \leq \binom{\lambda_i}{2}/2$ for all $1 \leq i \leq k$. You can check that there are no such partitions.

Comment: I got zero too.  So are there any non-zero values except $f\left(\frac{m(m+1)}{2},m\right)=1$?

Comment: Yes, there are plenty. e.g $f(10,7) = 2$ (I believe these are the smallest parameters such that $f(n,m) > 1$). Also $f\left ( \frac{m(m+1)}{2}, m \right ) = 0$ for all $m$ since there is only one way of writing $m(m+1)/2$ into a sum of distinct parts from $\{1, \dots, m \}$, namely $1 + 2 + \cdots + m$ and these parts do not satsify the condition mentioned in the previous comment.

Comment: The correct formulation of the condition should be $\lambda_1 + \cdots + \lambda_i \leq \binom{\lambda_i+1}{2}/2$ for all $1 \leq i \leq k$.

Comment: From the recurrence I think $f(10,4)=f(6,3)=f(3,2)=f(1,1)=f(0,0)=1$, while  $f(10,7)=f(10,6)+f(3,6)=f(4,5)+f(-3,5)=f(-1,4)+f(-3,4)+f(-8,4)= \ldots=0$

Comment: The following matlab code generates my sequence (perhaps the initial condition should be stated for $f(n,1)$ as in the code instead). Note that the sequence counts something, so should be zero for negative parameters.                                                                                     function f = paths(n,m)

sum = 0;
if (m == 1 || n < 0)
    if(n == 0)
       sum = 1;
    else
       sum = 0;
    end
else
    cutoff = ceil(nchoosek(m,2)/2);
    if n <= cutoff
       sum = paths(n,m-1) + paths(n-m,m-1); 
else
       sum = paths(n-m,m-1);
   end
end


f = sum;